# menu borders, current menu borders css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this kind of menu structure

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="current-menu-item currrent_page_item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and a css for the menu

```
#navigation{float: right; padding: 10px 0px; display: block;}
#navigation li{float: left; display: inline;}
#navigation li a{
padding: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;

display: block;

}

#navigation li{
padding: 0px 2px;
border-left: 1px solid #292929;
border-right: 1px solid #605f5f;
}
#navigation li:first-child{
border-left: none !important;
}
 #navigation li:last-child{
border-right: none !important; 
}

.current-menu-item a, .current_page_item a{
background: #414141;
border: 1px solid #4b4b4b !important;
border-bottom: 1px solid #323232 !important;

-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #353333;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #353333;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #353333;

-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;

behavior:url('border-radius.htc'); 
}
```

as you can see in styling, it produced a menu with a left and right border and a pushed like background with box shadow in the current menu, my problem is, the borders in the both left and right side of the menu looks ugly when the current menu is on between and I want to get rid of those borders. I mean for example, when the current menu is the About menu, now the left side border of the Contact menu must be removed as well as the right side border of the Portfolio menu, in that way things will look neat and cool.

Currently Im looking for a way on how to make it that way but no luck so far.

Comment: use left border only, and right just for the last one, or just right will look better (no border next to home button)

Comment: I don't know why you want to hide the surrounding elements' borders not the current one ! may you explain why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bit of jquery:

```
$('.current-menu-item').css('border','none');
$('.current-menu-item').next('li').css('border-left','none');
$('.current-menu-item').prev('li').css('border-right','none');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sDFzS/

Comment: brilliant! works like a diamond! thank you, when i read your post, i realize that it was easy at all, i just dont have the idea and jquery is out of a bit in my mind when im dealing this issue. hehe

Comment: I know the feeling - happens to me all the time!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with pure CSS as follows (see [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/N76FZ/)):

```
#navigation {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: block;
}
#navigation li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
#navigation li {
    padding: 0px 2px;
    border-left: 2px solid #292929;
}
#navigation li:first-child,
.current-menu-item, 
.current_page_item,
.current-menu-item + li, 
.current_page_item + li
{
    border-left: none !important;
}

.current-menu-item a, 
.current_page_item a {
    background: #414141;
    border: 1px solid #4b4b4b !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #323232 !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #353333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #353333;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #353333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    behavior:url('border-radius.htc');
}
```

Basically, the idea is this:

- Only use border-left
- Remove the border on

  - The first item (`#navigation li:first-child`)
  - The current item (`.current-menu-item, .current_page_item`)
  - The item immediately following the current item (`.current-menu-item + li, .current_page_item + li`)

Comment: (+1) Well approach. [Not supported by some older versions](http://caniuse.com/#search=Adjacent), but good anyway.

Comment: this works thank you very much yet i need two borders, however this is good, Ill take save this for future reference.

Comment: Purely out of interest, why do you need two borders?

Comment: (+1). I always prefer solutions which dont involve Jquery

Comment: @vee: thats my objective to my desired output